# How to make search functionality in Listview and refresh that list

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am trying to make a `ListView` with a search functionality.

But the problem that i am facing is that though I am getting the filtered list after using filter(`CharSequence`) the positions of objects on list remains to be the positions that were before the filter. Thus when I click on the item after a search it responds with the earlier item i.e., the list is not getting refreshed.

I am using this piece of code:

```js
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((SimpleAdapter) PlayListActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s);
    }

});
```

What should I do to make it work the way I want i.e, when I enter the input text ... it searches and refreshes the list so when I attempt clicking an item it responds with that item only and not the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account the filter() methods are asynchronous.

Try to use the SimpleAdapter.filter(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterListener listener) method instead of the filter(CharSequence constraint) one with your own FilterListerner object and when the filter completes call the adapter notifyDataSetChanged() to inform the list to refresh.

---

Edited (added example code):

```
((SimpleAdapter) PlayListActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
               PlayListActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         PlayListActivity.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     }
                });
        }
 });
```

Comment: Can you show me through the code? I am not getting about the functionality of Filter.FilterListener.

Comment: I changed it to :

((SimpleAdapter) PlayListActivity.this.adapter).getFilter().filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
     
     public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    });

But it still aint working..:(

Comment: Actually notifyDataSetChanged() function itself aint working... I am sorting my list in my code and then when I try to call notifyDataSetChanged().. it doesnt responds... the list remains in the same order... I then had to create a new adapter everytime and then call setListAdapter() to get the list in sorted list but still there too when I click on a list-item.. the item that were installed at that position before sort are responding and not the current item...:/ Do u reckon it is because of Multithreading problem ??

Comment: You are right, I forgot notifyDataSetChanged() must be run on UI thread. I just editted the code to reflect this. Apply your NPE bugfix too ;-)

Comment: I use above code .. It is checking serially .. Not considering middle words .. How to solve it ?